# MYSQL case if join is meant than perform subquery loop?

Tags: mysql

Sorry if the title is confusing I'm not sure the correct approach here.

This may be confusing but I have the following query to generate a temp table of students and I want to link this to the second query :
http://pastebin.com/mHybk9c7

And I have the following stored procedure - This proc grabs students completion results via a set of scalar subqueries.
http://pastebin.com/WF7evQSH

The problem is I can pull an individual students grades - and I can pull every class and every students activities (about 100m records...) but I can't pull on the class level. I can't do this because of the subquery and I can't seem to find a workaround

tldr: I run the second query to pull every student and every course grades. Or I can add a where to the main query or subquery to get a specific student. But I want to get every student for a specific course (based on the temp table)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: there are so many tables involved i dont think I can provide a database scheme example. It's the moodle database though

Comment: Perhaps you mis-read the accepted answer.